# How can I get this with XPath

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm writing a Crawler for one of the sites and and came across with this problem.

From this HTML...

```
<div class="Price">
    <span style="font-size: 14px; text-decoration: line-through; color: #444;">195.90 USD</span>
    <br />
    131.90 USD           
</div>
```

I need to get only **131.90 USD** using XPath.

Tried this...

```
"//div[@class='Price']"
```

But it returns different result.

How can i achieve this?

**EDIT**

I'm using this C# code (simplified for demonstration)

```
protected override DealDictionary GrabData(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html) {
var price = Helper.GetInnerHtml(html.DocumentNode, "//div[@class='Price']/text()");
```

}

Helper Class

```
public static class Helper {
    public static String GetInnerText(HtmlDocument doc, String xpath) {
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
        if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0) {
            var node = nodes[0];
            return node.InnerText.TrimHtml();
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public static String GetInnerText(HtmlNode inputNode, String xpath) {
        var nodes = inputNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
        if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0) {
            var node = nodes[0];
            var comments = node.ChildNodes.OfType<HtmlCommentNode>().ToList();
            foreach (var comment in comments)
                comment.ParentNode.RemoveChild(comment);

            return node.InnerText.TrimHtml();
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public static String GetInnerHtml(HtmlDocument doc, String xpath) {
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
        if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0) {
            var node = nodes[0];
            return node.InnerHtml.TrimHtml();
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public static string GetInnerHtml(HtmlNode inputNode, string xpath) {
        var nodes = inputNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
        if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0) {
            var node = nodes[0];
            return node.InnerHtml.TrimHtml();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using to grab the HTML in the first place? HtmlAgilityPack? LINQ2XML?

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Comment: @Arran I updated the question and added the code being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath you tried is a good start:

```
//div[@class='Price']
```

This selects any `<div>` element in the Xml document. You restrict that selection to `<div>` elements that have a `class` attribute whose value is `Price`.

So far, so good - but as you select a `<div>` element, what you will get back will be a `<div>` element including all of its contents.

In the Xml fragment you show above, you have the following hierarchical structure:

```
<div> element
    <span> element
        text node
    <br> element
    text node
```

So, what you are actually interested in is the latter text node. You can use `text()` in XPath to select any text nodes. As in this case, you are interested in the first text node that is an immediate child of the `<div>` element you found, your XPath should look like this:

```
//div[@class='Price']/text()
```

Comment: @Zafar: Is it still? I tested with [this online XPath testbench](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and it shows `Text='131.90 USD'` as a result.